# web service in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, web-services

Can we write a web service in objective c.Please help me out , i m in confusion

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can! You can just use `printf` and CGI to do this. (Like you'd do with Python, Ruby, Perl, PHP, Shell Script, Malbolge, etc…).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Content-Type: text/html\n\r");
  printf("\n\r");
  printf("<h1>Hello, world!</h1>");
  return 0;
}
```

Compile using this:

```
$ clang *.m -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
$ mv a.out index.cgi
```

See the documentation of your web server for information on how to enable CGI.

---

Or you can do it the die-hard way by writing a server in Objective-C. It's not very difficult.

Comment: :We should host it on mac or can we do it on windows systems also??

Comment: @sujay You can also host it on a Windows server of course, but you need to compile it for Windows then. Note that Foundation isn't available for Windows from Apple, but you can use [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/) (which is an open source port).